# iterate over anchors by id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have next jade/pug code:

```
#pm_language.dropdown(aria-haspopup='true', aria-expanded='false')
      button#langbutton.btn.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='dropdown') Lang [RU]
      .dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-right
        a#1.dropdown-item.active(href='#ru') Русский
        a#2.dropdown-item(href='#en') English
```

so the idea is to toggle anchor active classes

I tried to do some kinda iteration at some action for all anchor elements in #pm_language container, to find that one with id == '2' but had no luck:

```
 $('#pm_language').each( $('a'),

            function(i) {

                var elem = $(this);
                var id =  elem.attr('id');

                if ( id == '2' ) {
                    if ( !elem.hasClass('active') ) {
                        elem.addClass('active');
                    }
                } else
                    elem.removeClass('active');
            }
        );
```

Can someone point my nose where is me wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the id - why try to find it? -simply remove the class from all the `<a>`'s then target the one you want to have the active class. Incidentally - it is more common to have a ul with the dropdown menu class - and then have '`<li>`' elements that house the '`<a>`' elements. Then the active class goes onto the li - not the a.

But the following code is remove the active class from the existing a's and then add it to the desired one.

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').removeClass('active');
$('#2').addClass('active');
```